# Need help with understanding »kneifst« in this colloquial conversation

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I am asking for help in understanding the meaning of this conversation. I know most of the words but as I am a relative beginner, I am not sure I completely follow. I have included my understanding of each sentence but I kindly request anyone else's more knowledgeable interpretation:

> Ach ne, das kannste ja nicht so, da war ja was.

»Ne« I think is slang for »nein« or »kein«. If so, I get this.

> Du wolltest mir da ja noch irgendwas mal zeigen.

"You wanted to show me something." I get this.

> **Hab ich das so gesagt?
>   Das hat was mit Begabung und Talent zu tun, das kann ich dir nicht zeigen oder beibringen.

"Have I said this? It has to do with talent, that I cannot show or teach". This is completely clear to me, but it is the following sentence that I cannot follow:

> Ha ja, du kneifst ja dann immer.

I simply do not understand »kneifst« and, thus, the entire sentence is lost on me.

> Nö, das nächste mal nicht. Schwöre.

Since I do not understand the previous sentence, I'm at a loss on this. Something about "next time", but I feel this is shorthand slang.

> Ptft!

Obviously a verbal expression but have no idea of its cultural meaning.

Could someone help me over the rough spots?

Comment: Are you trying to ask a question? If so, I missed it. Please check here how to properly ask: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Comment: Yes, sorry. I can understand most words in this conversation but I'm missing a few and I think there is some colloquial slang mixed in to the point where I do not understand the full meaning and drive of this conversation

Comment: So you should write, which words you understand and how and which words you are missing. You are right, this is mostly colloquial slang, but to help you, one should know, where your problems are.

Comment: well, for example. I do not understand kneifst. I think its an expression as opposed to a literal word. ptft also has me confounded. So again, I can translate most of the individual words but I'm not able to discern the actual meaning of the conversation as a whole. From what I know and can translate, it is a bit choppy to me. I'm a beginning student in German after having lived there a few decades ago as a very young child.

Comment: @Tofro: I clarified the question to "could someone help me over the rough spots?" Otherwise the OP gave the context, made his best guesses, and expressed his doubts. That's good enough for a question.

Comment: I understand that this question has made some development from being a request for a explanation to a certainly much more appropriate serious question. However, it is covering so many individual words that it is clearly too broad. — I'm going to fix some typos and improve the readability now, but I'd ask you to narrow your question down. You can still ask several questions.

Comment: Besides, I've noticed that the edits sometimes made small changes to the dialog (and my change did so, too). These changes are mostly 'best guesses' to fix some typos or minor mistakes, but looking at them in the history, I get the feeling that were clearly some misinterpretations. It would be helpful if the dialog was correct and complete. You might want to check this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a transcript of a colloquial conversation, perhaps of some parent and a child, probably from the southern parts of Germany.

The original transcript uses some unnecessarily irritating spelling. Obviously the conversation has been transcribed by somebody with little awareness of *Umlaut* (ä, ö, ü) and of the regular use of capital letters.

Here is a 'translation' into more regular German and regular spelling. In square brackets I add some help in English for the more 'slangish' expressions.

> A: Ach nein, das kannst du ja nicht so. Da war ja was. ["Oh I see, you are actually not really able to do this. I remember that now."]
>
> B: Du wolltest mir da ja noch irgendwas mal zeigen.
>
> A: Hab ich das so gesagt?
>
> B: [Nonverbal answer, probably like "Yes, you did."]
>
> A: Das hat was mit Begabung und Talent zu tun. Das kann ich dir nicht zeigen oder beibringen. ["This is about being talented. It cannot be just taught.]
>
> B: Ha ja, du kneifst ja dann immer. ["Well, you always back down in these situations."]
>
> A: Nee, das nächste Mal nicht, ich schwöre es! ["No, next time I will not back down, I promise."]
>
> B: Pfft! ["I doubt this"]

**Kneifen** is a completely regular word. You can look it up in any dictionary. Attention, there are two basic meanings: 1) pinch 2) back down.

**Pfft** is a common way to express disagreement/doubt/contemptuousness in oral informal language.

**Nee** is a colloquial form of 'nein'. I recommend writing this 'nee' with two 'e', pronounced as a long vowel, because there is also "ne", with a short vowel, which is colloquial for "nicht wahr?" [right?].

The other parts should be comprehensible by using a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, when I tried to translate Kneifst there was nothing and I was asked if I meant Kneifen. I have never seen Kneifst so I was quite confused.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that all sentences are said alternately by A and B. Following this dialog, person B does first ask for A showing him something and then saying that he (B) is not able to show it to A. That just doesn't make sense whatsoever.

Comment: I also think that the first sentence is complete. "Da war ja was" => I can recall that you told me that you can't do this.

Comment: Hello EM1. Yes, you are right about the messed up sequence of A and B in my initial answer. I fixed this by adding a nonverbal answer by B. - I also accept your comment about the first utterances possibly being complete sentences. Indeed they could appear in certain everyday situations.

Comment: I'm a bit encouraged that native speakers are also finding this confusing because it certainly confused me as a beginner. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

> A: Ach **ne**, das kann**ste** ja nicht so, **da war ja was**.

*Ne* ist short for *nein*. *Ach ne, …* is a fixed phrase meaning "Oh, I remembered, …".

kann**ste** is a typical shortening of kann**st du**.

*da war ja mal was* is a fixed expression referrering to "some event" in the past.

> B: Du wolltest mir da ja noch irgendwas mal zeigen
>
> A: Hab ich das so gesagt?

That's plain German, no slang, no dialect, no shortenings involved.

> B: Das hat **was** mit Begabung und Talent zu tun, das kann ich dir nicht zeigen oder beibringen.

*Was* is short for *etwas* here.

> A: Ha ja, du **kneifst** ja dann immer.

*Kneifst* is second person singular of *kneifen*. The appropriate meaning here is in the dictionary. Look it up.

> B: **Nö**, das nächste Mal nicht **, schwöre.**

*Nö* is another shortening of *nein*.

*… , schwöre.* is "Kanak Sprak", a slang coined by youngsters of mostly Turkish immigrant background. Pronouncing the *ch* of *ich* as *sch*, pulling together subsequent "*sch*s" (thus leaving out the *ich* completely) and using the verb *schwören* way too often are distinct features of that sociolect.

People not using using that slang would say *Nö, das nächste mal nicht, **versprochen**.* instead.

> A: **Pfft!**

An onomatopoeia. Puffing up your cheeks.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that all sentences are said alternately by A and B. Following this dialog, person B does first ask for A showing him something and then saying that he (B) is not able to show it to A. That just doesn't make sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

*Kneifst* in this context can be translated as *chicken out*.